# WKWebView WebCrypto alert on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, webkit, wkwebview, keychain

While using a `WKWebView` on **macOS** I get an alert with the following message while visiting some websites:

> *MyApp* wants to use your confidential information stored in "*MyApp*
> WebCrypto Master Key" in your keychain. To allow this, enter the
> "login" keychain password.

This alert seems to appear just for certain websites, not all of them, and just a few times. After a few tries (clicking **Deny** on the alert and reloading the website) the alert stops appearing.

It seems that the alert only appears when the app is installed from the **AppStore**, I have never seen it while running the app directly from Xcode, not even when changing the scheme to `Release` configuration. This had made it really difficult to debug, without success so far.

Apparently there is not much difference if I click **Deny** or **Allow** on the alert, nothing seems to change on the website.

The app doesn't use at all anything related to the **Keychain**, so I know there is no code on my app potentially giving a reason for this alert to appear, still I find it very disturbing because:

- I don't really know what is triggering this alert.
- I don't know why, and what would happen if a user clicks on **deny**, or **accept**.
- I find the alert message very misleading as it makes it look like the app wants to do something with the user's keychain, and it makes it sound fishy, and cryptic.

For those reasons I would like to know more about the reason of this alert, and more importantly, how to prevent it to keep appearing.

Comment: I would try downloading a third party browser app and going to those websites to see if the same thing is triggered. The WebCrypto master key is something that WebKit accesses (I don't know when or why, but I see it in their source: https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/search?q=webCrypto).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the leads @LouFranco. This gave me the idea to also open a ticket requesting more information directly on WebKit, hoping they can clarify a bit more.

Comment: Also, you get 2 free support tickets with Apple each year.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @user2719160 No luck so far.